# Error in conversion of dates in java

Tags: java, android

```
String date = jsonobject.getString("needbydate");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy");
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
Date startDate = sdf.parse(date);
String needbydate = df.format(startDate).toString()+"";
```

### What is happening::

- **At the start**

`date`=`2014-12-17T21:37:00+00:00`

- **At the end**

`needbydate`= Dec/18/2014

`17` is changed to `18` .... What wrong am i doing in conversion

---

### EDIT:

```
            String date=jsonobject.getString("needbydate");
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date startDate;
            startDate = sdf.parse(date);
            needbydate = df.format(startDate).toString()+"";
```

Comment: can you try with `HH` instead of `hh`? Capital h is for the 24hours format

Comment: I am getting the 17th fine but I have no `Z` on the SDF as it is causing an Unparseable date exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date formats are using the system default time zone. That's okay for your input, because it specifies the UTC offset explicitly - but for your output, you've just got a date. So it's showing you the date that that point in time occurred in your system time zone.

You need to think about what time zone you *want* it to be - and whether that's affected by a non-zero offset in your input. You can use [`DateFormat.setTimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-) to set the time zone to be used on output. (For example, should 2014-12-17T21:37:00-05:00 show as December 18th (UTC) or December 17th (source time zone)?)

You should also be using `HH` in your input format instead of `hh`, as it's clearly a 24-hour value rather than a 12-hour value.

Comment: Thanks for the input .... Please see the edit .... Is this what you are refering ... I have used `jodaLibrary` for this ... How can i learn about these conversions any resource(I beginner in this concepts)?

Comment: @Devrath: Well no, I never suggested moving to Joda Time, although that's generally better. It's not clear why you're using a specific time zone here, or what's wrong with what I actually suggested. If you *do* want to use Joda Time, you'd be better off using a `DateTimeFormatter` for the parsing, instead of passing the string into the constructor.

Comment: Oh ... k how to use  `DateFormat.setTimeZone` any sample .... i am not able to read the docs and imprint it (newbie to these concepts )

Comment: @Devrath: you call it with the time zone you want the output to use. I don't know what else there is to say...

Comment: @Devrath To learn Joda-Time, simply search here on StackOverflow for "joda". You will find hundreds of practical examples. Much easier to learn when you see problem->solution rather than just reading the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

### With the help of JonSkeet resolved this ... Complete solution ...here

```
            String date=jsonobject.getString("needbydate");
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date startDate;
            startDate = sdf.parse(date);
            needbydate = df.format(startDate).toString();
```

Comment: Why the concatenation of an empty string at the end?

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

Much easier in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) indeed. Joda-Time handles that standard ISO 8601 format string by default.

When the input string includes an offset (`+00:00` in this case), the rest of the string is parsed accordingly. When passing a time zone object at the same time, Joda-Time adjusts the parsed value to that zone. See the code example below for a demo.

Note how the adjustment for Kolkata India means the date rolls over from the 17th to the 18th.

```
String input = "2014-12-17T21:37:00+00:00";

DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = new DateTime( input , zone ); // Parse as UTC because of "+00:00" offset, then adjust to desired time zone of Montréal.
```

Easily adjust to other time zones.

```
DateTime dateTimeParis = dateTimeMontréal.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeMontréal.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeKolkata = dateTimeMontréal.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal: " + dateTimeMontréal );
System.out.println( "dateTimeParis: " + dateTimeParis );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeKolkata: " + dateTimeKolkata );
```

When run.

```non
input: 2014-12-17T21:37:00+00:00
dateTimeMontréal: 2014-12-17T16:37:00.000-05:00
dateTimeParis: 2014-12-17T22:37:00.000+01:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-12-17T21:37:00.000Z
dateTimeKolkata: 2014-12-18T03:07:00.000+05:30
```